# Render has no/broken materials

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image]
Both Eevee and Cycles give me the effect on the right.
I have a few projects created from scratch in Blender with same issue
What's more, they all work nicely in Quixel Mixer and after import to Unreal.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please check it as answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple copies shown for the rendered version.
You have to disable the visibility for the final render with this camera icon.
The errors appear because the faces are overlapping and Blender is unsure which object to depict.

[image]

Comment: I feel so silly, Blender is full of traps

Comment: Don't worry. It takes some time. After Six years i sometimes still fall for exactly this error :D